# Qlikview use IN rather than = in a variable in an expression

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis, qlik-expression

I have a variable in an expression that SELECTS bottles.

```
sum({$<[PCC] ={"$(=concat([MCC],'","'))"},[RCPT] ={'Bottle'}>}[Amount]*-1)
```

I would like it to be able to select where RCPT equals bottle OR laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IN` values need to be contained in `{'value1', 'value2', 'value3'....etc}` but still using `RCPT =`

```
Sum({$<[PCC] ={"$(=concat([MCC],'","'))"},[RCPT] = {'Bottle', 'Laptop'}>}[Amount]*-1)
```

Comment: if you add [RCPT] *= {'Bottle', 'Laptop'} then you can even have the expression respond to selections of either Bottle or Laptop as well